# Exporting table into another access file from ODBC

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an sql server Database with an ODBC connection. I would like to be able to import a table from sqlserver into a access database.

I have been able to import a table into access and then export that into another access file.

Like so:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", _
  "ODBC connectionstring" _
  , acTable, "SOURCE1", "DEST1", False, True

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", _
  "P:\Main-Copy.accdb" _
  , acTable, "DEST1", "DEST2"
```

Would it be possible to do it in one step instead of two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider even a pure SQL solution where you connect to SQL Server database and remote Access database in same action query. Below examples assume MSSQL and MS Office are installed on same bit-version (32/64-bit) to connect appropriately via DAO.

**Append Query** *(assuming all fields align between both tables, otherwise select specific columns)*

```sql
INSERT INTO [P:\Main-Copy.accdb].DEST2
SELECT *
FROM [ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=INSTANCE\myServer;database=dbName;UID=XX;PWD=***].SOURCE1;
```

**Make-Table Query** *(assuming no prior table exists, otherwise need to `DROP TABLE ...`)*

```sql
SELECT *
INTO [P:\Main-Copy.accdb].DEST2
FROM [ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=INSTANCE\myServer;database=dbName;UID=XX;PWD=***].SOURCE1;
```

Comment: Thank you thats 100% what i want

Answer (score 0):

Robert,

Do you want to make a copy of the data? If not , is simply attaching the table in the 2nd database (in your example) an option? In this scenario, the data is never moved into the Access DB, but rather fetched when requested (i.e. double click the table in the database container). If the table is attached in the 2nd DB, then you can run a Make Table query to bring the data local, which would be  single step.

You can also push the data from SQL Server to the DB, assuming the SQL Server has access to the correct DB path.

Comment: Yes, I need the data

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out in a bit of a round about way

With this in the first database. Which calls a sub in an external database

```
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")     
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "DATABASE PATH", False     
appAccess.Run "ImportTableToExternalDB", "Clients"     
Set appAccess = Nothing
```

and this method in the external database. Which does the actual transfer

```
Public Sub ImportTableToExternalDB(TableName As String)

     DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", _
       "ODBC Connection String" _
       , acTable, TableName,  TableName, False, True

End Sub
```

Thank you to everyone for help

EDIT: I have decided to go with Parfait's answer as it was simpler and more efficient in every way.

Comment: This still feels like two steps and probably more overhead calling an Access object via COM.

Comment: It is definitely more round about than I'd ideally want, but this way it keeps I/O down which was my end goal

Comment: Again, you are launching a separate Access object then calling a macro with chances of runtime exceptions and having to release object from memory. This is all done with one-liner `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` step as you originally had.

Comment: I originally had to have two DoCmd.TransferDatabase Lines which doubles the network traffic, which I'm not a fan of. This isn't the way id like to do it but i still think it might be the best way. If you have a better option, I am more than willing to see your answer

Comment: Did you test performance? [DoCmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-object-access) is a robust framework in the Access object library, excellent at automating simple tasks like import/export. I am sure it written in Access' underlying C++ language and so robustly handles exceptions and read/write.